# blink an LED for 5seconds and stay on for 15minutes

Tags: button, timer, arduino, interrupt, led

I want my program to blink for 5 seconds if the button is pressed, and when the button is released, the LED will stay on for 15 minutes.
So far I have done the debouncing, but when I place the syntax of mine for the blink and stay for 15 minutes it does not work; when the program runs, it does not go through the loop of blink. The output is just when pressed led stays on, when released led stays off.

Here is my code:

```
int buttonPin = 2;    
int ledPin = 13;      

int ledState = HIGH;         
int buttonState;             
int lastButtonState = LOW;   


long lastDebounceTime = 0;  
long debounceDelay = 50;   

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);


    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
}

void loop() 
{

    int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (reading != lastButtonState) 
    {
        lastDebounceTime = millis();
    } 

    if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) 
    {

        if (reading != buttonState) 
        {
            buttonState = reading;

            if (buttonState == HIGH) 
            {
                int cntr=10;

                do
                {
                    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   
                    delay(200);  
                    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    
                    delay(200);                
                    cntr = cntr-1;
                } while (cntr!=0);

                digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
                delay(16000);
            }
        }
    }

    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    lastButtonState = reading;
}
```

---

**edit:**  Here is my circuit, I'm using a spark core basically its the same the only difference is the pins.

[image]

Comment: I have tested your code, it works fine for me, i have just added `ledstate = LOW;` after `delay(16000);` to power off the led. Haven't you a circuit problem ? could you post how you have connect the wires ?

Comment: My result : 'Run program'  `1- Led Power ON` 2- `I pressed button` 3- `Led blink` 4- `Led Power ON 16sec' 5- 'Led OFF' `

Comment: still no progress, the button is working with the led but it still doesnt blink the way it should be.http://tinypic.com/r/m998jo/8 here is my circuit, im using a spark core basically its the same the only difference is the pins. but talking about the program, its exactly the same

Comment: no luck my friend @JérômeTeisseire

Comment: i have used this circuit : http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button

Comment: regarding to your result, is the button pressed when the LED is powered on for 16sec? because i want it to be on when not pressed.

Comment: it works fine now! but why is it that when i pressed again the button for the second time, it does not exit from the loop of blinking?

Comment: Because in the loop of blinking you don't test the state button

Comment: what should i do? please help. noobie in arduino.